# How to Play M3U8 Format Android & iOS on Flutter

Tags: flutter, live-video

I can't find any solution for M3U8 Url player on iOS

I tried these plugins;

- video_player (Can't play)
- flutter_simple_video_player (Only support Android)

Comment: M3U is not video container, it is just text file with playlist.

Comment: I changed my question title, I forget "8"

Comment: M3U8 its a playlist like M3U. Try to open it with notepad or any text editor.

Comment: I solved my problem with Webview. Webview can play m3u8 Url (playlist) at both platform

Comment: Flicker_video_player

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`chewie`](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) lib will be used for playing m3u8 files

**Add Dependency**

```
dependencies:
  chewie: ^0.9.10
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://live-par-1-abr-cdn.livepush.io/live_abr_cdn/emaIqCGoZw-6/index.m3u8');
  late ChewieController chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample App"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Chewie(controller: chewieController),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this working on iOS? In my case, it stucks on an infinite loading...

Comment: Noted, thanks. I solved my problem, it was related to this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48670.

Comment: Is this working for web? @JiteshMohite

Comment: Use `late ChewieController chewieController;` instead of `ChewieController chewieController;` when sound null safety is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

yoyo player is best choice but this package dont support your project,
you can use this package, i changed yaml and update this package , for update flutter,

```
 yoyo_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/AmiirTorabii/yoyo_player_update
```

its work for me:)

Answer (score 0):

[YoYo player](https://pub.dev/packages/yoyo_player) is a great choice.

1. Add dependency:

`yoyo_player: #latest`

2. Use anywhere you want:

```
 YoYoPlayer(
       aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
       url:  "",
       videoStyle: VideoStyle(),
       videoLoadingStyle: VideoLoadingStyle(),
  ),
```

Comment: some devices it doesn't work like Techno Spark 3

Comment: yoyo_player : is not yet updated to work on flutter 2.5 , it shows some errors related to deprecated screen package...

Comment: Yoyo player seems not maintained, and is not a good choice to use at the moment

Answer (score -1):

best option is better_player or Flicker_video_player