# Playing .m3u8 video from Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, m3u8, video-player

I have .m3u8 master file and its parts stored in a folder in Firebase Storage. How do I play this video in flutter app?

Usecase:
I have a TikTok-like UI, where each video is a document in Firestore. In each document I have link to master.m3u8 file stored in Firebase Storage.

I tried out this .m3u8 link: https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8
and it works fine with video_player.

Sample link to my master.m3u8 file: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/videos%2F10-31%2F1604100430027grBzLN0d9BQk0QtoTf9TWNe2ps02%2Fmaster.m3u8?alt=media&token=<token_goes_here>

Video Files:[image: .m3u8 playlist files]

EDIT:

I have tried using chewie as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57682604/how-to-play-m3u8-format-android-ios-on-flutter) along with video_player package., It gives me error as follows:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708): Source error.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708): com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:156)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(32708):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Content of my .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2410843,RESOLUTION=1080x1920,CODECS="avc1.42c02a,mp4a.40.2"
1604145635522grBzLN0d9BQk0QtoTf9TWNe2ps02%2F?alt=media

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=612343,RESOLUTION=1080x1920,CODECS="avc1.42c02a,mp4a.40.2"
1604145635522grBzLN0d9BQk0QtoTf9TWNe2ps02%2F1_playlistVariant.m3u8?alt=media
```

where `1604145635522grBzLN0d9BQk0QtoTf9TWNe2ps02` is the folder name inside which `0_playlistVariant.m3u8` and `1_playlistVariant.m3u8` files are stored. Do I need to change these lines?

I am following [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-make-a-serverless-flutter-video-sharing-app-with-firebase-storage-including-hls-and-411e4fff68fa) guide for creating a video sharing app in Flutter.

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Play M3U8 Format Android & iOS on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57682604/how-to-play-m3u8-format-android-ios-on-flutter)

Comment: No it did not, I have updated my question with more details of the error after using the solution you suggested.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Also wondering if you found a more permanent solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing security rules for Firebase Storage to allow read and writes. I can play videos with the url to master.m3u8 file via video_player package in flutter.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read; allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

Although this is a partial solution since database can be accessed by anyone.