# How can I play .m3u8 ( HLS ) video streaming channels in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, m3u8, flutter-video-player

I will be very grateful for help.

I have many .m3u8 network  which are video streams, and I want to play them inside a flutter app.

I'm aware of the video_player package but it doesn't seem to have the ability to play them.

Can you help

Comment: How you did this? can you please add your answer

Comment: Chewie player is (imo) the best player for Flutter. [Chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65640479/20903485.
If not, let's see how you tried to implement the `video_player` package.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I can’t comment to asked question yet. Points too low